# Weird things regarding boost_log_trivial, not logging anything in file

Tags: c++, boost

I made a simple program of boost log as follows, and it works,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>  
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>

typedef boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::sinks::text_file_backend> file_sink;

int main()
{
  //Set up logging
  boost::log::core::get()->set_filter  
  (  
    boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::info  
  );
  // Create a text file sink
  boost::shared_ptr< file_sink > sink(new file_sink(
    boost::log::keywords::file_name = "/var/log/a.log.%N",
    boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 100
  ));

  // Set up where the rotated files will be stored
  sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(boost::log::sinks::file::make_collector(
    boost::log::keywords::target = "/var/log",
    boost::log::keywords::max_size = 200
  ));
  // Upon restart, scan the directory for files matching the file_name pattern
  sink->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();

  sink->set_formatter
  (
    boost::log::expressions::format("[%1%][%2%]%3%")
      % boost::log::expressions::attr< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp")
      % boost::log::trivial::severity
      % boost::log::expressions::smessage
  );
  boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
  boost::log::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", boost::log::attributes::local_clock());


  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "hello, I am a log for testing";
  }

return 0;
}
```

And everything works fine.

I compiled it using:

> g++ test.cc -lboost_log  -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -lboost_thread -lpthread
>   -lboost_system

I have a source code of about 50 files. It was using BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) and etc. It can output everything to console without problem.

I then add the whole thing in the previous program in the beginning of the main function of my sources, but then no log was output to the log file.

The log file is created inside /var/log (by using sudo to run the program, but the file is just empty. Nothing is on the console too of course.

My program is compiled using the following,

> g++ ./http/*.cc ./*.cc ../l/database/*.cc ../lib/ipc/ipc_fifo.cc -I./
>   -I./http/ -I../lib/ -std=c++11 -lboost_system -lboost_log -lboost_thread -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -lpthread -lboost_regex -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lmysqlclient -lsqlite3 -lmp4v2 -o a.out

Anyone can share me hints on why boost_log_trivial is not outputting anything to file?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried creating and file and writing to it using `std::ofstream`? Also using simple `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` macros to see if they output into the console?